# Trouble Using Denzcoskun Image Slider Within Fragment

Tags: image, kotlin

I can't seem to get the Image Slider by Denzcoskun to work within a fragment. All I get is a white box, when I test run the app. I'm still a n00b in Kotlin, so i'm sure I'm not doing something I'm supposed to, but I'd greatly appreciate some direction from anyone. Below is the .kt & xml code.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.memeing.R
import com.example.memeing.databinding.FragmentAnimalBinding


class Animalfragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_animal) {


    private lateinit var binding:FragmentAnimalBinding


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {



       val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animal,container,false)
        binding = FragmentAnimalBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


        val imageList = ArrayList<com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel>()

        imageList.add(com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel(R.drawable.memeing))


        val imageSlider = binding.AnimalImageSlider
        imageSlider.setImageList(imageList)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="431dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

  <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
      android:id="@+id/Animal_Image_Slider"
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="431dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know what to try.

Comment: I think i've narrowed it down. I have "val imageSlider = binding.AnimalImageSlider" but in the original code, it should be "val imageSlider = findViewById<ImageSlider>(R.id.image_slider)". I guess i'm messing up with using binding. I'm still struggling to figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: NEVERMIND! I FIXED IT! Proper code below:"val imageSlider = root?.findViewById<ImageSlider>(R.id.Animal_Image_Slider)

       imageSlider?.setImageList(imageList)

        return root
    }"